# How to convert DOC/DOCX files to PDF format using command in Raspberry Pi 4 Buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have installed Debian (Buster) OS without desktop in my Raspberry Pi 4 and want to convert DOC/DOCX files into PDF format by using a command line utility only.

Here I do not want to install any X11 packages.

1. I tried with `unconv` which require LibreOffice and it installs X11 Packages
2. I also tried with `pandoc` which requires Latex `texmaker` which will install X11 packages.
3. Command line utility `lowriter` and `soffice` are not available in Raspberry Pi 4 Buster OS.

Please suggest which command line utility should I use to achieve my goal as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose to install one of those options. Just because you're installing X11 libraries (and possibly related applications), it does not mean you'll end up with a graphical system.

(I run LibreOffice as a docx processor on a similarly headless system without any issues.)